# PHP autogenerated divs with delete button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

So I am learning PHP and mySQL, know HTML and JS. I am making a small note-taking webapp for my self, and stumbled upon a problem. I am generating divs by using a foreach and echo. The notes are stored in a db and requested using "SELECT"-mysql. The delete-button (works as a button but is text) is connected to a form which is also generated; One form for every note.

```
echo "<form method='post' id='" . $row['id'] . "form" . "' action='handler.php'>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='deleteRecord_button'";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='" . $row['id'] ."'>";
                echo "</form>";
```

When I submit the form using the delete-button a form is send as POST to a handler.php-file, however I can't seem to find a good way of sending the "id" of the note so that I can
delete it from the database using mysqli "DELETE FROM notes WHERE id = THE ID OF THE NOTE...

[image]

Sorry if this makes no sense, but I want to know if there is a good solution as to how I can send the id from notes.php (the picture below) to the handler.php file where I can handle and delete the note from the database. I prefer using "plain" JS, PHP, but I am using jQuery as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line ...

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='" . $row['id'] ."'>";
```

to

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['id'] ."'>";
```

Comment: Just to add to this, you'd then be able to access the ID value using `$_POST['id']`

Comment: It worked like a charm! I wasn't really sure what the "value" tag did, so I tried to send the id of the note through the id tag of the the div. I also did have a typo in the code, I forgot to end the <input>.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making your form field names contain the ID, you'd need something like this:

```
$formIDs = preg_grep('/^\d+form$/', $_POST);
foreach ($formIDs as $id_string) {
    $id = substr($id_string, 0, -4);
    ... do something with the ID ...
}
```

e.g..

```
<input type="hidden" name="42form" ?>
```

producing

```
$formIDs = array('42form');
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the value of the 'deleteRecord_button' input. If you add it like I did, it'll work.

```
<form method="POST" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>form" action="handler.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="deleteRecord_button" value="<?php $row['id']; ?>"/>
</form>
```

.

**Now, a tip you can ignore if you want.**

Instead of using a form to post a value to another page you can also use the GET method. This can be done with less code.

```
<a href="handler.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

If you catch the GET in handler.php and if necessary check if there is a user logged in and then execute the database command. If you do, make sure if the delete variable is a number. You could use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) for that.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I will be looking into that!